# Seantis Questionnaire - Django App

Tags: django

Where I can get user manual or tutorial for **seantis questionnaire** django application?

Answer (score 2):

Here's the [readme for Seantis Questionaire](https://github.com/rmt/seantis-questionnaire/wiki). The source code includes an [example app you can use for guidance](https://github.com/rmt/seantis-questionnaire/tree/master/example). Beyond that you're just going to have to figure it out by reading the source code.